# Getting the default value of Label in the Gridview if the one of the column value is null

Tags: asp.net

Below is my gridview

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableModelValidation="True" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand" onrowdeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting"> 
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="DimGray" >
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblamount" runat="server" Text='Label' ></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="DimGray" >
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblprice" runat="server" Text='Label' ></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

in the RowData_BoundEvent

```
  protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
     Label lbl2 = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblamount");
      if(amount>0) {lbl2.Text = amount;} else lbl2.Text = string.Empty;

      Label lbl3 = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblprice");
            if(price>0) {lbl3.Text = price;} else lbl3.Text = string.Empty;
```

If there is no value entered either in Amount or Price , I am trying not to display the values in the gridview if the amount is not greater than zero. But still, the grid displays Amount as Label and Price as Label if the condition does not satisfy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [GridViewRow's DataItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem.aspx) to get these values.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      // Retrieve the underlying data item. In this example
      // the underlying data item is a DataRowView object. 
      DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

      Double amount = (Double)(rowView["amount"]);
      Double price =  (Double)(rowView["price"]);

      Label lblamount= (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblamount");
      Label lblprice = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblprice");

      lblamount.Text = amount > 0 ? amount.ToString() : String.Empty;
      lblprice.Text  = price  > 0 ? price.ToString()  : String.Empty;
    }
}
```